# Retrieve the most duplicated value for a specific Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, unique-id

I am having difficulties programming this idea.

As you can see here in this sheet, ID no: 9999999 is the most ID listed in front of the documents mismatch.
Which mean ID no: 9999999 is the most one making this type of mistake.
In the other hand, ID number : 8888888 also is the most one making this mistake (wrong address).

[image]

So, what i want is when i type documents mismatch, ID no 9999999 should be retrieved.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula in `H2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10,G2)),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10,G2),0))
```

**Note:** As this is an array formula, enter it through pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down.

Comment: Your reference is wrong for row 2,  I think you copied row 3's formula, the `G3`s should be `G2`

Comment: Thank you @JvdV it worked, now i am trying to understand what it is in the formula.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner for editing very much appreciated.

Comment: @JvdV How if i want to use this code across multiple sheets ? $A$2:$A$10 sheet1 and sheet 2

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the dynamic array formula filter and your id's are numbers and not text:

```
=MODE.SNGL(FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10=G2))
```

If you ID's are text:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10=G2),MODE.SNGL(MATCH(FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10=G2),FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10=G2),0)))
```

If one does not have FILTER then the FILTER part can be replaced with `IF($B$2:$B$10=G2,$A$2:$A$10)`  In both formula and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.